# Query a range in an Excel table linked to PowerApps Text Search box

Tags: search, range, user-input, powerapps

First time asking a question here. As well as being pretty new to PowerApps as well.
I am trying to use two text input boxes for the user to define the min & max of their number range. basically i want the code to return all results that fall in the user defined range.
User inputs are:
`SearchText.Text`
`MinSearch.Text` and
`MaxSearch.Text`
`PDFData` is the table, and
`RMANumber` is the column that i want the Min & Max to search and return all within the user defined range. as of now, all i can get this to return are exact results, which just won't work for my situation. In my way of thinking, i want to add `WHERE` after the `RAWidth` and give greater or lesser arguments, but this isn't working for me. My full code is below, and any help is appreciated.

`If(SearchText.Text="" && MinSearch.Text="" && MaxSearch.Text="", PDFData, Filter(PDFData,SearchText.Text in PDFAuthor|| SearchText.Text in PDFName|| SearchText.Text in RMANumber|| MinSearch.Text in RAWidth))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression for your query:

```
Filter(
    PDFData,
    SearchText.Text in PDFAuthor || SearchText.Text in PDFName,
    Coalesce(Value(MinSearch.Text), -1) <= RAWidth,
    Coalesce(Value(MaxSearch.Text), 1000000000) >= RAWidth)
```

If the SearchText is empty, then the conditions `SearchText.Text in PDFAuthor` and `SearchText.Text in PDFName` will both be true anyway, so there's no need for the `If` at that point.

For the other conditions, we can use the functions [Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-value) / [Coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-isblank-isempty) to convert the text input to a number; if the user didn't enter anything (or entered an invalid number), then the function Value will return a blank value, and the Coalesce function will use the next value. I'm using here -1 for the minumum value and 1000000000 for the maximum - if the possible range of values in your RAWidth column is between those numbers then you're fine.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i needed and now i can move froward in my project. I did keep in the `If` statement though. It seems if i removed it, then i would get an "Unexpected token" error. `If(SearchText.Text="" && MinSearch.Text="" && MaxSearch.Text="", PDFData, Filter(
    PDFData,
    SearchText.Text in PDFAuthor || SearchText.Text in PDFName,
    Coalesce(Value(MinSearch.Text), -1) <= RAWidth,
    Coalesce(Value(MaxSearch.Text), 500) >= RAWidth))`                 This is my new, complete code that is working perfectly. Many Thanks!